# Which CSS property determines the vertical alignment of checkbox's text?

Tags: css, checkbox, vertical-alignment

The texts in my form don't vertically centerally aligned to the checkboxes. Do you know which CSS property determines this alignment?

[image]

Comment: You can do this with "vertical-align: middle".

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<div>
  <input class="checkbox" id="item" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-label" for="item">Lorem ipsum dolor est</label>
</div>

.checkbox {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Just add vertical-align.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/joiellantero/pen/bGBPOxx?editors=1100) to see before and after effect.

Comment: did you mean `vertical-align: middle`?